# Minimal Android API for an app integrated with Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I just watched [this I/O part](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRGyzqD-vRg&feature=plcp) and it's amazing. I was wondering if I could achieve something like Google Drive access (like for backup reasons) on my app that uses minimum API 7 (2.1). Anybody tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate Google Drive you will need the Drive API. The [developer guide](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/DeveloperGuide) for this SDK specifies 3 environments:

- Java 5 (or higher) standard (SE) and enterprise (EE)
- Android 1.5 (or higher) ([details](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android))
- Google App Engine

Comment: Using the Dive API on Android also requires using the new [Google Play Services APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services) that have not been released yet. Once it is, we'll release some sample code and tutorial to help developers get started with the Drive SDK on Android.

Comment: Alain: Is that actually necessary? It seems like plenty of people make posts suggesting they have made it work, and I feel like I've pieced enough things together to have it nearly working... if it is necessary, RELEASE IT. I've heard it's "coming soon" for months now. It seems like Google as a whole, and every responsible developer personally, aught to consider it embarrassing that their products (Android and Drive) don't play together.